# Updating state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code that renders a dropdown component from material ui and it's populated with data coming from a WS.

I set an initial value that is the firs element coming from the WS so when I render the page for the first time I can see the correct value in the dropdown.

My issue is when I try to select a different value on the dropdown, I'm not able to do it and I think is because I'm not updating the state, I have a method called "handleChange" but I'm missing something there but don't know what.

This is the code and hope someone can help with this, I'm new to react and still to practice much more.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

export default class WebserviceTest extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      selected: ''
    };
    this.renderOptions = this.renderOptions.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4';

    fetch(url)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          data: findResponse.results,
          selected: findResponse.results[0].name.first
        });
        console.log('----- ', this.setState.selected);
      });
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ selected: (value) });
  }

  renderOptions() {
    return this.state.data.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
          <MenuItem
            key={i}
            value={dt.name.first}
            primaryText={dt.name.first} />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {this.renderOptions()}
        </DropDownMenu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be very welcome!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In material UI dropdown, the selected value appears as third argument. So use something like this for your `handleChange` method

```
handleChange(event, index, value) {
 this.setState({ selected: (value) });
}
```

Ref: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu#properties

Comment: Thanks for your time, I add the and it worked... the thing that I'm not understanding is that they appear greyed (event and index) so I removed them but seems that those parameter needs to be there...

Comment: I think it's because you didn't use event and index. You don't have to worry at all